# Analyze a piece of code

Tags: bash, unix, properties, while-loop

I was analyzing the following piece of code. And I could not understand the line:

```
while read processinfo
```

What is `processinfo`? can i use any name instead of processinfo or is processinfo defined somewhere? Same goes for the use of "mailaddress" in while read mailaddress. Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash

serverlist=/home/path/serverlist.txt
emaillistfile=/home/path/emaillist

    cat $serverlist |  while read processinfo
      do

           processNameCount=`ps -ef | grep "$processinfo" | grep -v grep | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'|wc -l`

           if [[ $processNameCount -eq "0" ]]
             then
               cat $maillistfile | while read mailaddress
                 do
                   mailx -s "$processName  not running - `date`" $mailaddress 
                 done
           fi
    done
```

Comment: `processinfo` is a variable they are using that contains every time a line from `$serverlist`.

Answer (score 2):

`processinfo` is a variable being named by the code.  However, the start of this loop should really be re-written:

```
  while IFS=, read processName processLog foo; do
    processNameCount=...
    ... 
  done < $serverlist
```

There are undoubtedly other changes that should be made, but the UUOC and using read to get an entire line whichi is subsequently parsed with `echo` and `cut` is a travesty that must not go uncommented upon.

Comment: Also, the `processNameCount` assignment is awkward and inefficient. All it really does is equivalent to just `pidof "$processName" | wc -w`

Answer (score 1):

That line reads input from the file `$serverlist` and stores each line in a variable named `processinfo`

Answer (score 0):

`processinfo` is a variable used to store all lines of `$serverlist`(including empty), which means simply having the file content in your buffer. It stores one line at a time during iteration and executes till the last line you read from the file. Then you use the same in your further manipulations. This `processinfo` cannot be modified within your `while` construct.

Answer (score 0):

This construct:

```
cat file | while read varname; do <code>; done
```

means "for each line in the file `file`, execute the `<code>` with the value of `$varname` equal to the contents of the line".

`read` is a bash bulitin which reads a single line from standard input and splits it into fields. In this case, the standard input is provided by the command `cat`, and there is only one field, so the the entire line is assigned to `processinfo`.